# Server error(500) after deployment to railway in django

Tags: django, server-error

I was working on A Django project and it worked perfectly fine on the local server, especially when it came to form handling like user signup, login even admin login. But after I deployed it to Railway, first i got the error of csrf token, so it could not load any forms, which i solved with

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://domain_name.com']
```

which worked and now the forms load up but when after I fill in the details, the admin login, user sign up and login pages, and I hit the save but it throws back and error
"SERVER ERROR(500)"
I am really confused on what to do... someone please point me in the right direction please
Railway also throws back the following logs when i try to access the website features

````
[2023-08-29 08:22:35 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0

[2023-08-29 08:22:35 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7083 (1)

[2023-08-29 08:22:35 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2023-08-29 08:22:35 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9

Internal Server Error: /student/studentsignup

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection

self.connect()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

return func(*args, **kwargs)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect

self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

return func(*args, **kwargs)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection

connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect

conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "containers-us-west-49.railway.app" (34.127.80.91), port 7083 failed: Connection refused

Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner

response = get_response(request)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/app/student/views.py", line 34, in student_signup_view

if userForm.is_valid() and studentForm.is_valid():

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 201, in is_valid

return self.is_bound and not self.errors

^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 196, in errors

self.full_clean()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 435, in full_clean

self._post_clean()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 492, in _post_clean

self.validate_unique()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 501, in validate_unique

self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1229, in validate_unique

errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1339, in _perform_unique_checks

if qs.exists():

^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1241, in exists

return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 598, in has_results

return compiler.has_results()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1530, in has_results

return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql```
 Please Note the following:
1. I have not installed the PostgreSql on my machine, It was running smoothly during production process when I connected Railway postgres to my project.
2. I know momentarily switched my "DEBUG" to true and the following error exception was thrown back.
````

connection to server at "containers-us-west-49.railway.app" (34.127.80.91), port 7083 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?``` I hope this is helpful? What am I missing here?

let me share my requirements.txt just incase its needed to help solve this issue

```
asgiref==3.7.2
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
crispy-bootstrap4==2022.1
Django==4.2.4
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
django-crispy-bootstrap==0.1.1.1
django-crispy-forms==2.0
django-extensions==3.2.3
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.12
gunicorn==21.2.0
idna==3.4
packaging==23.1
Pillow==10.0.0
psycopg2==2.9.7
python-decouple==3.8
requests==2.31.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.4
whitenoise==6.5.0
```

Comment: Does the logs on Railway show anything useful?

Comment: Yes it does, am going to post them as edits in the original question

Comment: It seems like your database is not accepting connections from your Django app. You could try to look into your db settings. I'm not that familiar with Railway, but you could check if there is a rule/setting that determines which ip addresses the db accepts connections from.